# Using HttpResponseMessage to view errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I can use the following code which works fine to log in using my Web API.  However, whensomething goes wrong and an error is returned, I don't know how to get at the contect of the HttpResponseMessage.  If I just use the ReadAsStringAsync() method, I get the error in the string, but what type is it?  If I know the type I can get the object.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Login", loginObject);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var _logonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenResponseModel>();
}
else
{
    // an error has occured, but what is the type to read?
    var test = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

On the server it is returning;

```
BadRequest(ModelState).
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:  I have since resolved the issue like this;

```
var value = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var obj = new { message = "", ModelState = new Dictionary<string, string[]>() };
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(value, obj);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result returned back is an **JSON** object with a "**Message**" and a "**ModelState**" properties.

The "**ModelState**" state value is an object, whose properties are arrays of strings. The property list of "**ModelState**" varies from time to time depending on which property is invalid.

Hence, to get a strong-type returned response, why don't you manipulate the **ModelState** yourself on the server side, and then pass the object to the **BadRequest()** method

Comment: Thanks for this info.  It helped me resolve the issue using JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(value, obj);

Answer (score 2):

Here is just grabbing raw json in text of error message...

```
 if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {                                
    dynamic responseForInvalidStatusCode = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>();
    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer msg = responseForInvalidStatusCode.Result;
    result = msg.ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try IOStreamReader. This is vb.net, but that's not too hard to convert:

```
IOStreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream)
RespStr = IOStreamReader.ReadToEnd
```

Or

```
       Dim HttpReq As Net.HttpWebRequest = Nothing
       Dim HttpStatus As Net.HttpStatusCode = Nothing

      HttpResp = CType(HttpReq.GetResponse(), Net.HttpWebResponse)            
      'verify the response
      HttpStatus = HttpResp.StatusCode
```

Answer (score 0):

try following :

```
 try
    {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Login", loginObject);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var _logonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenResponseModel>();
            return _logonResponse;
    }
  catch (Exception ex)
    {
           throw ex;        
    }
```